# Microsoft graph api - outlook - Returns only latest mails

Tags: rest, outlook, pagination, microsoft-graph-api

The microsoft graph api for outlook https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages does not return all of the mails from the mailbox. And how to get mails between specific intervals of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$filter` clause to filter emails by date and time.

By date

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=ReceivedDateTime ge 2021-05-07 and receivedDateTime lt 2021-05-10
```

By date and time

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=ReceivedDateTime ge 2021-05-07T08:00:00Z and receivedDateTime lt 2021-05-07T12:00:00Z
```